# Method to Extrude polygon in caduceus wings

Tags: modeling, topology

What is the best method to Extrude polygon in caduceus wings?[image]

Comment: Hello, your question is hard to understand, what problem have you met with extrusion exactly?

Comment: Thank you. I am a Blender beginner, and the caduceus's wings have protuberances (plumage) as shown in the figure. How to achieve the protuberances (extrusions) on the surface of the caduceus wings?.

Comment: You mean you want to know how to redo the object you show? Or you want to change it? It's still not clear to me

Comment: Hi Tulio.. in the light of these comments, if you mean the stylized feathers on the wings, (my assumption?) , I think you could edit this post to make that a bit clearer

Comment: Excuse my lack of precision. I appreciate the help. The problem is how can I model the feathers of the caduceus's wings as shown in the attached figure? Is the texture of the caduceus wings achieved by extrusion or sculpting?

Answer (score 1):

Create this kind of topology:

[image]

Extrude once:

[image]

Extrude the faces one after the other and scale a bit down the extruded face:

[image]

Add some support edge loops if you want to sharpen a bit the edges, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Very grateful.